# Get text from span class: with Beautifulsoup and requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing python codeusing beautiful soup...i need to access the price 15999  from
15999

It doesn't have id element , it has only class tag. how to get 15999 from this ??

I tried below code:

```
soup  = BeautifiulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
tags = soup('span',{'class' : 'a-price-whole'})
for tag in tags :
  price = tag.getText()
```

this prints 15999 which is present in entire page

Comment: Can you share the html snippet containing the 15999 value you want to scrape? What do you mean by 15999 from 15999?

Comment: span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">₹</span><span class="a-price-whole">15,999</span></span>

Answer (score 0):

Presupposing that the corresponding element is also present in `soup` - Check the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) it is `get_text()` not `getText()`:

```
soup  = BeautifiulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
tags = soup('span',{'class' : 'a-price-whole'})
for tag in tags :
  price = tag.get_text()
```